# Cassandra Query by Date

Tags: cassandra, cql

How do I update a colum based on a greater or less then date in Casandra?

Example:

`update asset_by_file_path set received = true where file_path = '/file/path' and time_received = '2015-07-24 02:14:34-0600';`

This works fine. But I would like to do it for all columns that match this file path and `time_received` is greater then `2015-07-24 02:14:34-0600`.

time_received is date, clustering column.
file_path is string, partition key

Answer (score 1):

Cassandra's WHERE clause has many limitations and if you have several clustering columns things could not work as you expect, at least there are limitations for >, >=, <, <= etc operators. Here is a quite fresh [blog post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause) from Databrix about WHERE clause nuances, it also covers some upcoming features.

Answer (score 1):

I think UPDATE can only modify a single row at a time, so I don't see a way to update multiple rows on the server side in CQL.

A couple possible programmatic approaches:

1. Do a range query to return all the rows you want to update, and then on the client side, update each row returned.  Since they would all be for the same partition, you could issue the updates as batched statements.
2. If you have Spark available, you could read all the rows you want to update into an RDD using a range query.  Then do a transformation on the RDD to set the received value to true, then save the RDD back to Cassandra.